# __dirname is not representing the intended path

Tags: html, node.js, http

I'm currently struggling with an issue, trying to render an HTML file. Here's the code snippet below:

```
import http from 'http'
import fs from 'fs'
import path from 'path'

const __dirname = path.resolve(path.dirname(''))

const requestListener = (req, res) => {
    fs.readFile(__dirname + 'index.html', (err, callback) => {
        if(err) {
            res.writeHead(404)
            res.end(JSON.stringify(err))
            return
        }
        res.writeHead(200)
        res.end(callback)
    })
}

const app = http.createServer(requestListener)

app.listen(8080)
```

I'm not getting any errors on the console, however I'm getting the following on the browser when loading localhost:

`{"errno":-4058,"code":"ENOENT","syscall":"open","path":"D:\\..."}`

The status code given on the response is 404, which means I'm not actually able to load the HTML file. In addition, if I remove __dirname and pass the actual path within `readFile()` it works, though I wanted to understand why isn't dirname actually working when it should. Thanks in addition for your answers!

Comment: is your html file in the sample place as the file above

Comment: Do a `console.log(__dirname)` and see what it is. Then, do a `console.log(dirname + 'index.html')` and see what that is and see if it matches exactly where you placed `index.html` in your file system.  One of those will show you a problem.

Comment: Yes @UdenduAbasili, the html file is located exactly inside where __dirname is pointing to, I`ve just put it into a `console.log()` and the path is correct.

Comment: Hey @jfriend00, thanks a lot I was able to find the issue, it happens that I'm using windows and on path construction it uses a `'\'` instead of a `'/'`.